# How to get value of Bootstrap Toggle Buttons in PHP

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

I've used multiple Bootstrap Toggle Buttons for some options selection. On submitting form, I want to check which options are selected so that I can save the corresponding values in database using PHP. 
Below is how my HTML looks like (inside form) -

```
<li>
  <button type="checkbox" class="btn skillNameBtn" data-toggle="button" aria-pressed="false" autocomplete="off">
 Option1 </button>
  <button type="checkbox" class="btn skillNameBtn" data-toggle="button" aria-pressed="false" autocomplete="off">
 Option2 </button>
  <button type="checkbox" class="btn skillNameBtn" data-toggle="button" aria-pressed="false" autocomplete="off">
 Option3 </button>
</li>
```

My question is how do I get value of which options are selected in PHP script? E.g if its simple input field, I use $_POST[]. But in this case what is the way to do the same. 
Thank you in advance for help.

Answer (score 0):

You can input a hidden field eg:

```
<input type="hidden" name="option" value="" id="option">
```

And use a jQuery:

```
$('.skillNameBtn').click(function(){
    $('#option').val($(this).val());
});
```

You might add value="Option 1" etc into your buttons for easier work